OpenCV High Res Image Capture Broken in Raspberry Pi
I am upgrading to RPi 5 from my 4.  On the 4 I had opencv 3.2, which is old but it captured high res still images from my 48mp ELP camera.  I have now upgraded to opencv 4.6 and there have been some changes, mainly I had to add a second arg to VideoCapture.  I am working in Python 3.11.2
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 8000)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 4000)
ret, frame = capture.read
capture.release


This is the error that I am receiving
[ WARN:0@2.945] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1405) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
[ WARN:0@2.952] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (2401) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Internal data stream error.
[ WARN:0@2.953] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (897) startPipeline OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@2.953] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1583) setProperty OpenCV | GStreamer warning: no pipeline

To note this if I remove setting the width and height I only get the 1405 error but my image shows up in my next function as 1920x1080
I also tried cv2.CAP_V4L instead of cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, it does not error out but won't produce a high res image either.

ELP Camera? Can you be more specific about the exact camera? How it's connected? Why you think you must use gstreamer?

ELP is the brand name, it's their 48MP autofocus version. Connected USB.  Because I don't know what else to use.
Edit: I did solve my issue by using Picamera2, fast and it goes full resolution.  Though if anyone wanted to address this for future

lots of issues only happen in the raspberry pi ecosystem. might be it's a problem with raspberry pi.
